# Qt/C++11 throw, final override in method prototype

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, moc

On MacOSX Yosemite with clang I am unable to compile the file which contains the following method in the header (updaterplugin.h:47):

```
void update() throw(std::runtime_error) final override;
```

Clang says:

> -o moc_updaterplugin.cpp updaterplugin.h:47: Parse error at ")"

When I remove the `throw(std::runtime_error)` statement it compiles successfully.

Also interesting fact that this behavior depends on Qt somehow because plain C++11 code compiles successfully and errors like these usually come from Qt's **MOC**-classes.

Is there any fix for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that [exception specifications](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/except_spec) are [deprecated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Features_removed_or_deprecated) in C++11 (but the [noexcept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec) specifier is significant).

So just remove the `throw(std::runtime_error)`